# How to change address bar URL without redirecting the user (not using History API?)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I know it's a very common question around here. But I can't find answer that I'm looking for.

I need to achieve a very similar behaviour like Groupon.com does it. For instance, when you visit https://www.groupon.com/goods/all. On the left side you will see an "**Interest**" filtering widget and when you select one or more option, the page URL on the address bar will change to something like https://www.groupon.com/goods/all?interest=good-for-gifting.

In first place I thought that they are using the **History API** but they don't. Because when I check the `history.length` to see if it get increased, it always returns the same value.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe because they use replaceState() method which does not add any entry to the history but replaces the current entry

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Thanks a lot! That happens when you don't read the complete documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try URL Rewriting in htaccess or configuration files. You can refer below article.
http://webrewrite.com/url-rewriting-htaccess/

Hope this is useful!